# What are the key differences between Git Extensions and Git Source Control Provider?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, git, version-control, github

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507343/using-git-with-visual-studio) talks about solutions that allow working with github from Visual Studio.
As it turns out there are two main options:

- Git Extensions
- Git Source Control Provider

Could you summarize the key differences between them, so that I could make a decision which one to use.

The original question was asked and answered 4 years ago. If currently there are new viable options, I'd also like to hear about them.

Comment: I would think the new viable option would be the git tooling built-in to Visual Studio.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/01/30/git-init-vs.aspx

Comment: @EdwardThomson Omg! How could I have missed this!!! Thank you!

Comment: @EdwardThomson if you would like to put it as an answer, I will accept it. Cheers.