# Source Control for Xamarin /VS2010 cross-platform solutions

Tags: plugins, version-control, tfs, git-svn, xamarin-studio

I would like to know how to connect Xamarin Studio with a TFS (Team Foundation Server) for source control purposes or, if it's not possible, how to connect Visual Studio 2010 to Git.

I am already trying to use TFS from http://tfs.visualstudio.com/ and it's working great with VS2010 but I couldn't find a way to connect it to Xamarin Studio.

The goal is to manage all source codes in the same way - the developers are located in different places so the server should be placed in internet - and I think I will decide among TFS or Git. I tried to use the Git Plugin but it doesn't work with VS2010.

Is there anyone who already found a good solution? I know there's a plugin for VS2012 ([Using Git with Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507343/using-git-with-visual-studio)) but I found nothing for 2010 version.

I tried to use this too: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efS0kKvfi6k but I think it's not what I am looking for (reliable way to manage source codes from a server)!

I am ready to install and use other source control systems too, if they can manage sources from VS and Xamarin Studio.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to have a git-enabled team project. Then from Xamarin Studio click on version control menu then choose checkout. Enter your team project url tfs credentials to git clone it.

Xamarin studio integrates with git and subversion out of the box now, and will connect to any tfs projects that have been git enabled. (i don't use subversion so i can't speak to that one)

Comment: I know that I can easily manage a git-project in Xamarin Studio. I'd like to know how to manage TFS on Xamarin or Git on VS2010.

Comment: Ok, i must not be understanding what you are asking then. What do you mean by manage TFS on Xamarin? Have you tried the Git Extensions project [link](https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) and the plugins for VS2005 and up?

Comment: I'll give a try to the Git Extension for VS2005+. About Xamarin Studio: I know there's a plugin for TFS for the Mac version but I found nothing for Windows version to connect Xamarin Studio to a Team Foundation Server.