# Error when trying to build an MVC 4 project at Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, git, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC4 project. I have my project sync at Azure, using Git. I can build and run my project successfully at localhost. However, when I syncronize it, and the project tries to be build, It cannot, and I get the following error

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets (182): Could not copy the file "Scripts\js\jquery-1.6.4.min.js" because it was not found."
```

However I have this file, and I can open it from my visual studio. Do you know why this is happening

**EDIT**

I see that this file is the only one that has not a lock (checked in) besides it at solution explorer at Visual Studio. So probably is very related with this.

Do you know why, and how to add a lock besides it, in order for my project to run?

Comment: Just check it in and it should be copied successfully.

Comment: thanks @Abhinav. How do I do that?I found nothing at visual studio

Comment: If you do not have a VS extension for Git you can get one from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507343/using-git-with-visual-studio