# Cloning a GitHub project into Visual Studio 2013

Tags: github, visual-studio-2013

The canonical question on 'how to use Git in Visual Studio?' appears to be [this one posted by Herb Caudill](https://stackoverflow.com/q/507343/575530).

[One of the more recent answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19888635/575530) notes (correctly) that "[Visual Studio 2013 natively supports Git](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/26/visual-studio-2013-preview-version-control-tfbuild.aspx)".

So when I go to a Github page ([supercolider](https://github.com/supercollider/supercollider)'s is the one I'm trying to clone) and click on the 'Clone in Desktop' button I would expect (hope) that Visual Studio 2013 would take up the link and clone the repository. That is not what happens, instead Windows (I'm using 8.1) asks me if I would like to visit the store to find an app that can handle files of type (github-windows).

What is the correct way to clone a GitHub repository in Windows under Visual Studio 2013? The various MSDN pages (e.g. [Share your code in Git](http://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/share-your-code-in-git-vs) or [Setup Git on your dev machine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850445.aspx)) mention GitHub but do not explain how to use it.

Comment: It's useful if you down-vote to explain why in a comment so that the poster (me in this case) can learn from it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is super easy once you know how :)

From within Visual Studio 2013:

1. Select File -> Open -> Open From Source Control
2. The Team Explorer window will come up, one of the sections is "Local GIT repositories". In that section choose "Clone".
3. That will bring up a path selection textbox and directory browser.  Simply replace the default path with the git URL (in your case    "https://github.com/supercollider/supercollider")

Thats it!

Note: unless specified otherwise, Visual Studio will store the actual files here: 
C:\Users\\Source\Repos\

Answer (score 4):

What you do is go to the Team Explorer, click the Connect to Team Projects, select the Clone option and enter the URL of the Repo you wish to clone and press Clone

Answer (score 1):

To expand on neo12's answer & address the canonical question "how to use Git in Visual Studio"

I agree with neo12. Additionally you can also navigate directly to solutions from the Team Explorer "Local Git Repositories" section by double clicking them

Here is a walk through I put together to explain in concise detail. The video is less than 2 minutes. Let me know if this helps.

http://prestoasp.net/lesson/how-to-work-with-visual-studio-github/