# GitHub for Windows and Visual Studio 2013 - can they be used together?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, github-for-windows

I have GitHub for Windows installed on my dev machine and I'd like to have VS 2013 push/pull to/from it.  Is this possible?  And if so, how would I point VS to properly use GitHub for Windows?

Comment: Your question has actually been asked before (not specifically for GitHub, however). Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507343/using-git-with-visual-studio. I think it should help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use them together. But I don't know what you mean by "I'd like to have VS 2013 push/pull to/from it". GHFW is just a means to access the git repository; the repository is stored locally like if you were using git from the command line.

Obviously you can setup VS and GHFW to point to the same repository on disk.

Depending on where you have your source code hosted, [this](http://michaelcrump.net/setting-up-github-to-work-with-visual-studio-2013-step-by-step) is an excellent guide to setting up VS2013 using Github. I currently have it set up using Bitbucket (although I don't use GHFW anymore, because VS is good enough for me).