# Git for visual studio 2008

Tags: git, visual-studio-2008

I did a migration from `svn` to `git`. I have seen a built in svn for `Visual studio 2008`.

Is there any built in `git` available for `visual studio 2008` or let me know the best way to work.

Comment: just install git and if you hate to enter commands using git command prompt then install source tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take look at [Git Extention](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8f594baa-e44e-4114-8381-e175ace0fe97), more explaination on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507343/using-git-with-visual-studio).

Comment: Any Idea for `Tortoisegit` with VS 2008

Comment: certainly you can use external client like tortoisegit or even commandline cli client, but everything when you do `git pull` you have to refresh your VS  2008.

Comment: **vs 2008 is not supported by Git Extension**. See [GitExtensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HenkWesthuis.GitExtensions)